# Why the downvote hate on this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I'm trying to get an idea of why my question earned 2 downvotes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264761/how-can-i-make-a-simple-share-to-imgur-button

This is a legit programming question (not about specific code, per se, but trying to accomplish a particular user experience); I searched the Internet and Stack Overflow to see if there was already an answer and no luck.

If there a better place on the Internet to ask a question like this, I'm open to it. But considering everything else and who is most likely to know the answer, Stack Overflow seems like the right place...

Comment: Never do this there is an unfortunate reddit effect.

Comment: Because Stack Overflow isn't a place where you can ask any question where somebody might know the answer. It's about certain types of questions, which this is not one of. "Give me some code that would produce this button" isn't what SO is about.

Comment: _I searched the Internet and Stack Overflow_ Show the fruits of that research.

Comment: @ChrisHayes It should be noted that he didn't specifically ask for the code to implement it, he asked what approach to take. Both are not good, but the explanation required to explain why it's wrong is a bit different.

Comment: @niton Better to find out why it received a negative reaction and endure the one time reputation loss than to continue to receive negative reactions in the future for an unknown reason.

Comment: The question seems half-baked, over-broad and not well researched.

Comment: You could have copy pasted the text of the question so people would have to search for it to bypass the site protocols and downvote a question they would not normally see. Edit - Except for the insistent downvoters.

Comment: @niton That would be trivial, anyone can check his question history anyways.

Comment: Yeah thanks @niton, you're right... I should have never even asked... and now I see my question was deleted. For the record, haters ;-) I was NOT asking for code, I was asking for some direction. I did plenty of research before checking here on SO, without luck. As a long-time SO user, I would have happily edited my question to clarify and improve its quality if it had been flagged instead of deleted. I'm annoyed that instead of being given the chance to improve my question (and document my research, etc.) it was just zapped and I got dumped on. Very irritating and lame of the community. :-\

Comment: not the whole community.... I didn't even see the post

Comment: @Eric Like I stated in the comment on my answer, the deletion was probably to protect you. Anyways, don't take it personally. You asked an unclear and overbroad question, but it's not going to have a long-term affect on you. Learn from it, and move on and you'll continue to have many happy and productive days here.

Answer (score 20):

The question shows no research effort, and is basically asking for someone to use off-site resources to answer your question. Exactly like you can do yourself.

On SO, it's better to do your own research and make your own attempt at solving the problem. Then if you run into problems with your implementation, that'd be a better time to ask a question, explaining your goal, what you tried to do, and what your implementation is. Often someone will fix your attempt, and if there's a better way of doing it, someone will often provide that too since you showed some effort.

Another issue is that you asked what approach to take, but didn't describe *any* specific requirements, meaning someone can close it as Too Broad. Are you trying to do it all from client side? Do you want to involve a server side framework? Where's your relevant code at accomplishing this task?

You updated your question and asked if there's a better place to ask it. That's not Stack Overflow's job, to tell you where to ask questions, since we're not responsible for what's on-topic at other sites. We can only be held accountable for what's on-topic at this site. But a reasonable starting place might be any developer forums or other social media platforms that imgur provides for its developers. Though I'd suggest there you'd be more specific than what you did in your question on SO.

Comment: Except I was looking for simple direction, not specific code. I would have appreciated just a few sentences suggesting an approach as an answer. If my original question was too broad or not well phrased or I didn't make it clear that I already did EXTENSIVE research, then-- as a long time member of the SO community and someone who wants to contribute to a better overall corpus of knowledge-- I would have been completely willing and happy to edit the question and improve its quality. Now I don't have that option since it's been deleted. Pretty lame.

Comment: @Eric and *"simple direction, not specific code"* isn't what SO is about. If you haven't started implementing, Programmers might be a better bet.

Comment: @Eric I can't speak for exactly why your question was deleted, but I suspect it was to *protect* you from the meta effect. If the question had just been closed or downvoted, you could have edited it back into shape. Unfortunately once you come to Meta, so many people will see it in the "bad" shape and take immediate action.